# Ruby https POST with headers and auth error

Tags: ruby, http

I'm trying to sent a post request that like so based on curl:

```
curl -XPOST -H content-type:application/json -d "{\"date\":\"2012-07-02\",\"aaaa\":\"bbbbb\", \"cccc\" : \"\[\"dddd\",\"eeee\",\"fffff\"\]\"}" URI -u USERNAME:PASSWORD
```

In Ruby:

```
@toSend = {
    "date" => "2012-07-02",
    "aaaa" => "bbbbb",
    "cccc" => ["dddd","eeee","fffff"]
}.to_json

uri = URI.parse("https:/...")
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host,uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true

req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
req.body = "[ #{@toSend} ]"
req.basic_auth options[:username].to_s, options[:password].to_s
post = https.request(req)
```

For some reason the auth isn't getting attached what could be wrong with this?

Comment: make sure you are sending username and password as strings

Comment: From the command line as `"USERNAME" and "PASSWORD"`? I am currently doing that.

Comment: I mean in ruby make sure you are passing strings like options[:username].to_s and options[:password].to_s

Comment: Didn't help, but added that in just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your request to be run before you even add the auth parameters.
I would go this way:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

url = URI.parse('https://....')
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url.path)
req.basic_auth options[:username].to_s, options[:password].to_s
req.use_ssl = true
req.form_data({"date" => "2012-07-02", "aaaa" => "bbbbb", "cccc" => ["dddd","eeee","fffff"]})

resp = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port).start {|http| http.request(req) }
```